# link not working with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Probably a very simple answer, but I cannot seem to find a working solution. I am creating links from a php search script and it generates links based on query. I have written a sample jQuery script to open a div based on a  tag being clicked, but when I click link, nothing happen. I cannot see any errors in firebug and would appreciate somke help. Thank you.

**UPDATE**: Added html and changed mailLink from id to class.

jQuery

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.mailShow').fadeIn(1500).html('This is the mailShow div');



    });
```

PHP

```
<?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsd))

{?>

    <div class="each_rec"><a href="#" class="mailLink"><?php echo $row['name_usr'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row['idcode_usr'];?></a></div>

<?php

}

    if($total==0){ echo '<div class="no-rec">No Record Found !</div>';}
?>
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">

    <div class="search-background">

        <label><img src="loader.gif" alt="" /></label>

    </div>

       <div id="sub_cont">

        <div class="mailShow"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Generated HTML from firebug

```
<div class="each_rec"><a href="#" class="mailLink">Demo User&nbsp;&nbsp;DEMO</a></div>
```

Comment: You're using the same ID for each `<a>` tag. I don't know if it's related to the problem, but IDs must be unique.

Comment: Is your jQuery code within the document ready handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jquery you have `.mailShow` and in PHP you use `id="mailLink"`. You should change `.mailShow` to `#mailLink`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqYR5/) for testing.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hwvh6/)

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click","a",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('.mailShow').fadeIn(1500).html('This is the mailShow div');

        });
 });

<?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsd))

{?>

<div class="each_rec"><a href="#" class="mailLink"><?php echo $row['name_usr'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row['idcode_usr'];?></a></div>

<?php

}

    if($total==0){ echo '<div class="no-rec">No Record Found !</div>';}
?>
```

Comment: Why is this necessary? He's not adding the links dynamically.

Comment: Your code is correct but it will produce bugs, since he's using the same ID on all anchor elements.

Comment: ok return some error? have you change into the code php with mine?

Comment: Yes I have but still same result

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with jsfiddle.net

Comment: Could it be that you have put your html in the main page whereas mine is called from a search in a seperate php page?

Comment: FYI. Firebug reports this an error: TypeError: $(document).on is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).on("click","a",function(e) {

Comment: Have you include in that page jquery? I advise you to download the last version of jquery

Comment: Yes, Jquery library is loaded and showing as ok in net of firebug. When I do a search and results are returned, it appears fine in firebug just no click from jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I see two probable issues:
1. You didn't use $(document).ready(); and put your code outside of it. Then you need to put the above code to docyument ready.
2. You inseert links dinamycaly - from ajax query. Thus you need to use jquery delegates instead.

Comment: This is how I tried delegate: $("#content #sub_cont .each_rec").delegate("a","click",function() {
        

  $('#content #sub_cont .mailShow').fadeIn(1500).html('This is the mailShow div');

  

 });

Comment: Have you put your code into $(document).ready(function() {});?

Comment: Yes I have and still no different